# How to get the text of a button in actionscript 2?

Tags: actionscript-2

I tried `trace(playBtn.text);` but only got a `undefined`,anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, it's been a while since I've used AS2.

Turns out when it comes to `SimpleButton` you can't access dynamic text or other objects that are located within them.

You could always create a movieClip and have it have two layers, one that contains the SimpleButton and one that contains a Dynamic Text field that you can modify.